# Engine power and torque of a vehicle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, mathematics

Having the Power/Torque-RPM curves of a vehicle, how can we derive the engine power equation and the torque out of these curves with respect to time?

Comment: What do you mean with respect to time? time it takes to change from 2000 rpm to 4000 rpm delivering the same power?

Comment: I Need to calculate the fuel flow consumption (mf)' over time. Inside the mf (fuel flow consumption) formula the engine power is requested. How can I calculate the power engine?

Comment: Could you give an example of the fuel flow consumption formula you're attempting to utilize? If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to calculate the fuel flow rate (kg/s) by knowing the power produced in an internal combustion engine at a specified RPM? 

If I'm not mistaken, you're going to require an efficiency curve for this as well.